# Is the concurrency a feature of the JavaScript language?

Tags: javascript, api, browser, ecmascript-6, v8

Is the concurrency a feature of the JavaScript language ?

Can we say JavaScript as a language is concurrent language ?

As mentioned in this great video (JavaScript is concurrent language)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

But why we are saying that JavaScript is concurrent if all the concurrent apis are part of the browser apis (ajax, events, timers) ?

Comment: It is said because JavaScript has been improved for backend side also. So many of websites are implementing it rather than using php (Apache Server) for example.

Comment: Because many people (wrongly) consider the browser APIs to be part of the language.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses the concept of a single-threaded event loop, opposed to multi-threading in Java. The code to be executed is managed by the event loop in the job queue.

More at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: Not exactly. JavaScript as employed in browsers does use this concept, but not the language in itself.